# What is difference between get_bloginfo('url') and get_site_url()?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, bloginfo, site-url

I am developing a plugin.

I want to know difference between

```
get_bloginfo('url');
```

and

```
get_site_url();
```

I got same output, then what's the difference?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- **`get_bloginfo('url')`** calls `home_url()` calls `get_home_url()` reads option `home`
- `get_bloginfo('wpurl')` calls `site_url()` calls **`get_site_url()`** reads option `siteurl`
- `get_bloginfo('siteurl')` and `get_bloginfo('home')` are deprecated arguments and return `get_bloginfo('url')` (`siteurl` argument is documented wrong in Codex as equal to `wpurl`, [it's not in current code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L404))

The difference is that these two function chain to different options, which are typically same.

It would be more appropriate to compare `get_bloginfo('url')` to `get_home_url()` or `get_bloginfo('wpurl')` to `get_site_url()`. Then the answer is that these functions are on different level in chain. Typically the deeper function is - the more flexible it is and the less filters output passes through.

Answer (score 4):

From 'wp-includes/general-template.php'

```
function get_bloginfo( $show = '', $filter = 'raw' ) {

switch( $show ) {
      case 'home' : // DEPRECATED
      case 'siteurl' : // DEPRECATED
        _deprecated_argument([snipped]);
      case 'url' :
        $output = home_url();
        break;
      case 'wpurl' :
        $output = site_url();
        break;
```

So:

- `get_bloginfo('home')`, `get_bloginfo('siteurl')` and `get_bloginfo('url')` are equivalent to calling `home_url()` (also note that the use of **home** and **siteurl** as get_bloginfo parameters is deprecated)
- `get_bloginfo('wpurl')` is the same as calling `site_url()`

Comment: `get_bloginfo('siteurl')` is long deprecated and currently **is** same as `get_bloginfo('url')` (`home_url()`). It would make more sense for it to equal `get_bloginfo('wpurl')` (`site_url()`) but for some reason it doesn't. I see that Codex says otherwise, well - code is different from documentation. [Source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L404).

Comment: ok...interesting and confusing. editing my answer having looked at the code!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the parameters over at Codex:

**[get_site_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_url)** / 
**[get_bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo)**

Comment: I am looking for specific difference between the two

Comment: checking the codex would allow you to see specific differences between the two.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, the primary difference between `home_url()`/`get_site_url()` and their `get_bloginfo()` analogs is that `home_url()`/`get_site_url()` return the proper http/https scheme, while `get_bloginfo()` doesn't.

Comment: Incorrect, `get_bloginfo()` simply calls `site_url()`/`home_url()` functions and will return proper scheme just as they do.

Comment: Oh neat! Looks like that changed since the last time I looked at `general-template.php`. :)