# Will get_bloginfo('url') return URL with backslash?

Tags: urls

Based on my test, get_bloginfo('url') will not return backslash, so it will return URL like this:

```
https://www.example.com/blogs
```

In this post [What is difference between get_bloginfo('url') and get_site_url()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16161/what-is-difference-between-get-bloginfourl-and-get-site-url), it is said get_bloginfo('url') calls home_url().

And, in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086865/why-does-the-trailing-slash-appear-after-url-when-using-home-url-in-wordpress, it is said home_url() will return URL with backslash.

So, I am confused. Anyway, I want to find a function to return URL **with** backslash.

Comment: Note that the correct trailing slash for an URL is a forward slash / not a backslash `\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Codex example for home_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/home_url/#comment-428) says you want `home_url( '/' )` to get the blog's URL with a trailing slash.

Alternatively you could use `trailingslashit( home_url() )`. That may be safer if your site's home option somehow ends up stored with a trailing slash, since it looks like get_home_url() assumes it isn't, but that ought not happen.

Answer (score 0):

> it is said get_bloginfo('url') calls home_url().

**Correct**, as can be [read in the source code](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/5.8.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L784-L786):

```
    case 'url':
        $output = home_url();
        break;
```

> it is said home_url() will return URL with backslash

**Wrong**. [In the docu it says](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/home_url/), that `home_url()` will return the "[h]ome URL link **with optional path appended**" (emphasis mine).

---

If you want the home URL to always have the trailing slash, you can use the `home_url` filter, because under the hood, `home_url()` will use [`get_home_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_home_url/):

```
add_filter('home_url', function (string $url): string {
    // already has trailing slash
    if (substr($url, -1) === '/') {
        return $url;
    }

    // add trailing slash
    return $url . '/';
}, 10);
```

(or much less readable but a one-liner)

```
// force trailing slash
add_filter('home_url', fn (string $url): string => $url . (substr($url, -1) !== '/' ? '/' : ''), 10);
```

However, this might break some existing implementations, that rely on `home_url()` not returning the trailing slash, so use at your own risk!

Comment: There's the built-in [trailingslashit](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/trailingslashit/) too, so you could possibly just `add_filter('home_url', 'trailingslashit');` (untested)

Comment: @Rup Good catch, totally forgot about it